# Font Awesome Icons in Offline

Tags: css, html, font-awesome, cdn

Is there any way to use this in offline?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I copy the link and save as font-awesome.min.css but still it is not working in offline like this  link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

[image]

Comment: save the font-awesome.min.css to your project directory and refer that path as href

Comment: i used font-awesome.min.css but it is only square showing

Comment: clear you cache and check. or you might given wrong path

Comment: use this link to download [https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/fontawesome-free-5.0.9.zip](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/fontawesome-free-5.0.9.zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the "Download free" button and make sure that you have the webfonts too. There is a `web-fonts-with-css` folder in the downloaded zip. Copy the fonts in your project and modify the paths for the fonts in your CSS to point to the location of the webfonts.

If you open the CSS linked in your questions you'll see that they have some imports with

`url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0')`

modify these with the location of the fonts downloaded.

Comment: i copy and paste the link in url https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css but i cant see download free sir

Comment: just copy and paste to new file and refer that file

Comment: there is two file of eot, which i will link? fa-solid-900.eot and fa-regular -400.eot

Comment: still i dont understand sir should i replace all?, including ?v=4.7.0

Comment: the ?v=4.7 is for caching the fonts, I would leave that out for now and use just the file name.

Comment: replace just the folder name, if it's different (after you copy the downloaded folder with fonts). The file names should remain the same.

Answer (score 9):

1. Download the font awesome free zip from the official site
2. there is a folder called 'css', copy that folder into your project folder, (important) and also copy the folder named 'webfonts'
3. then link the desired css file to html file (all.css or fontawesome.css or fontawesome.min.css) using the command
4. then try your code, it will work

Answer (score 4):

The Fontawesome website itself documents how to download and use the icon kit offline here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Answer (score 2):

Here is all around solution for you:

1. Download [FontAwesome ZIP file](https://fontawesome-v4.github.io/get-started)
2. Create an `assets` folder on your `public_html` (or your root folder)
3. Extract all the content of `font-awesome-4.7.0` into your `assets` folder
4. Edit your HTML file `head` tag and add the following code (i.e. after all `meta` tags):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 2):

The best way Is to use svg instead of font awesome because if u look at it font awesome takes time to load which is a bad thing in 2022 as it just load fonts, you could perhaps just use svg which is quite faster and takes no time to load, you could use this website to get svg of any fonts and I'd recommend it as it is best free and gives you customized icons as well
https://iconify.design/

Comment: I tried this out and it's great. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right version of those files.
Assuming you only need the fonts & css for version 4.7.0.

[DOWNLOAD](https://github.com/Zartax666/AFonts4.7.0.git)

1. Move fontawesome.css to your main directory and include it in your html file:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./fontawesome.css'>
```

2. Make a sub-folder called fonts and place the fonts (eot, woff2, svg, ttf) there.

That`s it.

Notes:
Current fonts path in the fontawesome.css is :

```css
src:url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');src:url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

You can move them anywhere you like but make sure to correct the paths.

Comment: I tried above, but getting 415 Unsupported Media type.                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                       
.../font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Referrer: .../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score -1):

none of above solutions worked for me,
But I recently found a solution for it in fontawesome's website it is simple and  works well and I thought it worth sharing.
Here it is:

```
<head>
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!--load all styles -->
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="far fa-user"></i> <!-- uses regular style -->
  <i class="fal fa-user"></i> <!-- uses light style -->
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i> <!-- uses brands style -->
</body>
```

As you can see it imports all.css file