# how to use font awesome icons in CSS offline

Tags: css, font-awesome, webfonts

I want to know, how can I use the font awesome's offline icons with `:before` or `:after` pseudo in CSS?
If I use CDN instead of offline then it Works perfectly but not with offline files.

```css
.mydiv::before {
    content: "\25AE";  
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
 }
```

Comment: What you mean by offline not working?

Comment: You need to download the fontawesome files. See this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550011/font-awesome-icons-in-offline

Comment: @VimalPatel Means offline downloaded icons

Answer (score 3):

How to set it up depends on your solution. Are you using simple CSS or any CSS preprocessors?

Let's assume you are using simple CSS:

1. Download and extract the package
2. Copy two folders: */webfonts* and */css/all.css* into your project’s static assets directory (or where ever you prefer to keep front end assets).
3. Link it in the head tag of every HTML page that you need

like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

For more info, take a look at the official guide on how to host it by yourself: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Comment: It works fine when I use it with Html file like `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>` but it's not work when I use it with css file using `:before` or `:after` pseudo.

Comment: I will try to set it up and let you know

Comment: It's most likely a problem with the "content" property of the ::before o ::after element. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559526/how-to-add-the-font-awesome-icon-in-after-before-elements

Answer (score 0):

Download required file from Font Awesome website
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

- Create a new folder /fonts/
- Unzip the download into this folder.
- Then add `<link href="fonts/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>` section.

It is easy to use them in your webpage, for examples see https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use